# Is there tutorial for creating interface in RQT?

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on nav2d simulation and I want to create user interface for this simulation. Is there any tutorials or reading materials that helps to understand and use rqt for creating interface that can communicate with the simulator ?

If it is not possible in rqt and if I create an application in QT software then, is it possible to communicate with ROS ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230626/is-there-tutorial-for-creating-interface-in-rqt-?/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to learn more about `rqt` you might want to start at http://wiki.ros.org/rqt which contains information about what you can do with `rqt` as well as tutorials to create your own plugins for it in either Python or C++.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-04-15**:
Thanks :).